# href scheme keeps changing from http to https

Tags: ssl, https, cloudflare

The task is as trivial as it can get: I need to get `http://` link on the site, BUT I always getting `https://`. So, I'm putting something like this on the page: `<a href="http://link-to-my-site" rel="nofolow">Link text</a>`, but navigating to the page I'm getting the same link but with `https://` scheme.

I did had `Composite.Navigation.HttpsEnforcer` package installed on the site. It should not be the cause of this behavior, but I removed it anyway - no luck.

Maybe its something obvious, and I'm not seeing things straight because right now is 4AM here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue is not related to Composite C1 at all.

I recently changed the website's DNS to Cloudflare and it has "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" setting which doing exactly what I was experiencing on my website:

> Automatic HTTPS Rewrites helps fix mixed content by changing "http" to "https" for all resources or links on your web site that can be served with HTTPS.

Disabling this setting solved my problem.